# Integrate Bugnet to Subversion

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, subversion-edge

I need to integrate bugnet tracker to subversion. Can anyone provide me a best solution to do this?

**Note:**

1. My svn is on the other server
2. Bugnet application is in the other server

Answer (score 0):

Just [follow the instruction](https://github.com/dubeaud/bugnet/wiki/configure-source-code-integration#user-content-subversion-svn). Ask if you have any question in particular. Otherwise, the question will be closed as offtopic.

Comment: i followed the step which you have been given.i commited change in the subversion with id but it is not that change is not showing in the bugnet tracker